# Parse PFFile Swift viewing text file

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage, pffile

I can view pictures from Parse on `UIImage` but I can't view a `.txt` file stored onto Parse on a `UIImage`. I know if the document is larger than 10MB you must save it on the cloud. This `.txt` file is small. Please help.

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if let objects = objects 
  {
     for object in objects 
     {
        if let resultView = PFUser.currentUser()?["file"] as? PFFile 
        {
           //Thats NOT unwrapped ? Need to use !
        resultView.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
             if (error == nil) 
             {
                  let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                 self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                println(data)
              }
         }

       }
    }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't populate a `UIImage` with a text file.

You are going to end up doing some useless hackery in order to circumvent simply storing a `String` and using a `UILabel`.

I suggest storing a `String` and populating a `UILabel` or a `UITextView`

But then again, it depends on your use case. What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
   if let resultView = PFUser.currentUser()?["file"] as? PFFile
```

should be replace by

```
let resultView = object["file"] as? PFFile
```

And also I don't think you could display `.txt` file into a `UIImageView`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `PFUser.currentUser()` is referring to the logged-in user. Since, you are querying the `_User` table. So, `objects` are an array of `PFUser`. What's the reason why you need to loop through all the `objects`?

It's okay to use `PFFile` for storing text file. Basically, you convert `NSString` to `NSData` and then store it into `PFFile`. When you read it, you should use the similar method to convert back to `NSString`. Here we go: `NSString* textString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

I think the wrong concept you have is: you think of a `.txt` can be handled directly by `PFFile`. You should find a way to load `.txt` into `NSString`. Then, you have the control.